# Not to stretch background to before pseudo element

Tags: css

```css
.n-bullet-silhouette-1-004077::before {
  background-image: url("/wp-content/themes/nonverbis/assets/img/cliparts/woman-silhouette/004077/silhouette_1.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  height: 3rem;
  max-width: 3rem;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.n-af8170 {
  color: black;
  font-style: italic;
  background: #af8170;
  background: linear-gradient(141deg, #af8170 69%, #f9fafa 100%);
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5% 50% 50% 50% / 50% 50% 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<p class="n-bullet-silhouette-1-004077 n-af8170">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

[image]

With reference to the picture, I'd like the background for which .n-af8170 is responsible for be shown only above the text. That is not to cover the area of the before pseudo element. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I've added 3 styles to the first class and 2 to the second. As the picture is not visible, I added `content: 'test'` which you should remove back to empty string. And remove `float: left`.

```css
.n-bullet-silhouette-1-004077::before {
  background-image: url("/wp-content/themes/nonverbis/assets/img/cliparts/woman-silhouette/004077/silhouette_1.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "test";
  height: 3rem;
  max-width: 3rem;
  width: 100%;
  /*float: left;*/
  margin-right: 10px;
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -30px;
}

.n-af8170 {
  color: black;
  font-style: italic;
  background: #af8170;
  background: linear-gradient(141deg, #af8170 69%, #f9fafa 100%);
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5% 50% 50% 50% / 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p class="n-bullet-silhouette-1-004077 n-af8170">Lorem ipsum</p>
```

Comment: But if we run your code, "test" is above the text. Whereas I need it to the left.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your question. So you'd like the woman picture to stay where is it now, just the brown background to be moved to the right?

Comment: Woman without the background, text with the background.

Comment: @Kifsif, I've edited my sample above. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

How you are "creating" the width of your pseudo element, doesn't make too much sense. `max-width: 3rem; width: 100%;` will result in a width of 3rem, unless the whole parent was so narrow, that it isn't even 3rem wide itself to begin with. That case probably doesn't need to be covered, so you could just set `width: 3rem` instead. And with such a known width, you can easily add the same amount of margin-left to the `p` element, and then "drag" the pseudo element back to the left using either a negative margin-left, or relative positioning.

```css
.n-bullet-silhouette-1-004077::before {
  /*background-image: url("/wp-content/themes/nonverbis/assets/img/cliparts/woman-silhouette/004077/silhouette_1.svg");*/
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -3rem;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.n-af8170 {
  margin-left: 3rem;
  color: black;
  font-style: italic;
  background: #af8170;
  background: linear-gradient(141deg, #af8170 69%, #f9fafa 100%);
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 5% 50% 50% 50% / 50% 50% 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<p class="n-bullet-silhouette-1-004077 n-af8170">Lorem ipsum</p>
```